# woocommerce product variation select alert box customization

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It is possible to customize the product variation slection alert box?

I want to show bootstrap modal instead of default alert box.

I tried like below. but no lick.

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".single-product .single_add_to_cart_button", function(){
        jQuery('#Content').modal("show");
        return false;
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am looking.  I dont understand why everywhere else (in the cart and checkout) it uses wc_add_notice but in this instance it throws an ugly js alert box.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis, No. I didn't found any solutions.

Comment: I posted a solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

The Petar answer works better for me, but ***return false*** should be inside of  if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {..} to let botton work if enabled, so like this :

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function (event) {

    if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-is-unavailable')) {

            //Do your thing for unavailable variation

        } else if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-selection-needed')) {

            //Do your thing for not selected variation

        }
 return false;
    }
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution that will stop the alert and allow you to do your own thing.  You can add in your own validation as needed, it worked OK for me although I think somehow using wc_add_notice would be a better solution, I couldn't figure that out.

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the button
    // Do your custom validation here
    return false; // Prevent the Alert from firing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS class selector based approach.

Basically you are using click event and, with couple of nested conditional statements based on CSS selectors, executing your code. When code executes you return false to prevent alert firing.

Because we're conditioning ".disabled" class on ".single_add_to_cart_button" it is safe to use anywhere in your theme JS.

Tested and it works.

Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js#L94

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function (event) {

        if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-is-unavailable')) {

                //Do your thing for unavailable variation

            } else if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-selection-needed')) {

                //Do your thing for not selected variation

            }

        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

None of answers works for me so I found another solution.

Go to

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js

find (125 line)

```
VariationForm.prototype.onAddToCart = function(event) {
    if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-is-unavailable')) {
            window.alert( wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_unavailable_text );
        } else if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-selection-needed')) {
            window.alert( wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_make_a_selection_text );
        }
    }
};
```

and replace `window.alert` with your actions.

Beware that it may be overwritten with the new update of this file within woocommerce.